# How can I add data from class properties into a datatable

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview, datatable

I currently have a class with 4 properties

```
public class DataEntry
{
    public string Name { get; internal set; }
    public string Version { get; internal set; }
    public string TotalDownloads { get; internal set; }
    public string LastUpdated { get; internal set; }
}
```

I form a ConcurrentQueue of objects (using the previous classes properties)

```
var list = new ConcurrentQueue<DataEntry>();

foreach (var i in Enumerable.Range(0, 2))
{
    list.Enqueue(new DataEntry { Name = "TestName", Version = "Test Version", TotalDownloads = "TestDownloads", LastUpdated = "LestDate" });
}
```

I then return this ConcurrentQueue as a list

```
return list.ToList();
```

I am trying to populate a windows form datagridview with this data.

I understand that it is possible to populate the datagridview like this

```
DataGrid.DataSource = Class.Function();
```

However I would like to use a datatable as the datagridviews datasource.

To try and put this data into a datatable I have tried

```
private DataTable dataTable = new DataTable("dataTable");

private async void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dataTable.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
    dataTable.Columns.Add("Downloads", typeof(string));
    dataTable.Columns.Add("Updated", typeof(string));
    dataTable.Columns.Add("Version", typeof(string));

    foreach (var item in await Class.Function())
    {
        dataTable.Rows.Add(item);
    }

    dataGrid.DataSource = dataTable;

}
```

However this just puts all the data into the first column (along with the class name DataEntry at the front of the string)

How could I format the data into a datatable?

Comment: Try using `getMoreAddonsTable.Rows.Add(item.Name, item.Downloads, item.Updated, item.Version);` .. where `item.Name` goes to column1, `item.Downloads` goes to column2 and so on

Answer (score 0):

Using @o_O's advice I managed to modify the for loop to do exactly what I wanted

```
foreach (var item in await Class.function())
        {
            dataTable.Rows.Add(item.Name, item.TotalDownloads, item.LastUpdated, item.Version);
        }
```